# creating dataframe with a given number of rows and a repeated value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a dataframe with a given number of rows, say for instance it is `n` and with a unique value stored in a variable, for instance, `unique_value`.

Given `n = 6` and `unique_value = 25`, the expected output would be a dataframe with a single column, 6 rows and in all of them, a 25:

```
25
25
25
25
25
25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is using :
[`np.ones()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) which:

> Returns a new array of given shape and type, filled with ones.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.ones(n)*unique_value)
print(df)
```

---

```
      0
0  25.0
1  25.0
2  25.0
3  25.0
4  25.0
5  25.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
import pandas as pd

n = 6
unique_value = 25
df = pd.DataFrame([unique_value] * n)

#print(df)
#    0
#0  25
#1  25
#2  25
#3  25
#4  25
#5  25
```